# Pytest Html Report Unavailable

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to generate html reports for my pytests. I am seeing very odd behavior. First I am running on raspbian, using python 3.7.

I am running two commands

```
pytest --html=report.html DeviceTests/DisioOnUsb.py --device_id 9101 --firmware_version 0.1.1
```

and

```
sudo pytest --html=report.html DeviceTests/DisioOnUsb.py --device_id 9101 --firmware_version 0.1.1
```

Now I need to use sudo as I have not elevated this users permissions. If I run the first command pytest runs fine, creates the html but fails because some of the later operations require elevated user privileges'. The second command fails and tells me

```
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --html=report.html
  inifile: None
  rootdir: /home/pi/Documents/Disio Production Test
```

When I list my plugins, everything seems to be in order. What is sudo doing? Why can I not create this report using sudo?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/Disio Production Test $ pip3 freeze | grep pytest
pytest==6.2.5
pytest-html==3.1.1
pytest-metadata==1.11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve my issue I performed to actions

```
sudo pip3 uninstall pytest-html
```

followed by

```
sudo pip3 install pytest-html
```